# ACL along a directory-path

Tags: linux, acl

To access a file you need X-rights along the path.

So as an example if I want to access `/root/files/x.txt` from another user I need give him R-right on the file and X-rights on `/root` and `/files`.

Lets assume it should be only access to this single file and this single path. Is there a way to do it with just ONE `setfacl` command?

`setfacl` with option `-R` would change every object in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, setfacl does not have any option to automatically +x every parent directory. You would have to add some code either to setfacl, or to a separate program/script of yours for this to be done.